# Convert JSON to table using JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, excel

I am trying to write a logic to convert complex Json to a table in excel. I modified some source code from online converters. I have have an HTML file containing plugins for jquery, bootstrap etc. In my JS file viewer.js, I have the code to convert Json to a table however this uses HTML tags. This works fine when I launch HTML file in the browser.

But I would like to convert this to server side nodejs application without a browser. As of now, I am not able to just use the JS file because plugins are present in HTML file. Is there anyway that I can use the plugins directly inside JS file and then discard HTML file. I would like to just pass Json to Nodejs code and get a table content

```
(<table><.....></table>)
```

My final step will be to convert this table content to Excel sheet.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.jcubic.pl/js/jquery.splitter-0.14.0.js"></script>
    <link href="http://jquery.jcubic.pl/css/jquery.splitter.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
    <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "ur-b8756614-8756-d77-785e-7018db6c35ac", doNotHash: true, doNotCopy: true, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
    <script src="viewer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

viewer.js

```
jQuery(function(a) {
    a("#load_json_btn").click(function() {
        processJson()
    });
});

processJson();

function processJson() {
// This is where I trigger the method to build table
console.log(buildTable(getJsonVar()));
return 'response'
}
function getJsonVar() {
    try {
//var text = fs.readFileSync('./input.json');
console.log('inside getJSONVar')
        var a = $.parseJSON('{"a":3,"b":4}');
        return a
    } catch (e) {
        return $("#error_msg").text(e.message),
        $("#errorModal").modal("show"),
        {}
    }   
}

function buildTable(a) {
    var e = document.createElement("table"), d, b;
    console.log('a is not array')
    if (isArray(a))
    {
        console.log('a is array')
        return buildArray(a);
    }
    for (var c in a)
        "object" != typeof a[c] || isArray(a[c]) ? "object" == typeof a[c] && isArray(a[c]) ? (d = e.insertRow(-1),
        b = d.insertCell(-1),
        b.colSpan = 2,
        b.innerHTML = '<div class="td_head">' + encodeText(c) + '</div><table style="width:100%">' + $(buildArray(a[c]), !1).html() + "</table>") : (d = e.insertRow(-1),
        b = d.insertCell(-1),
        b.innerHTML = "<div class='td_head'>" + encodeText(c) + "</div>",
        d = d.insertCell(-1),
        d.innerHTML = "<div class='td_row_even'>" + encodeText(a[c]) + "</div>") : (d = e.insertRow(-1),
        b = d.insertCell(-1),
        b.colSpan = 2,
        b.innerHTML = '<div class="td_head">' + encodeText(c) + '</div><table style="width:100%">' + $(buildTable(a[c]), !1).html() + "</table>");
    return e
}
function buildArray(a) {
    var e = document.createElement("table"), d, b, c = !1, p = !1, m = {}, h = -1, n = 0, l;
    l = "";
    if (0 == a.length)
        return "<div></div>";
    d = e.insertRow(-1);
    for (var f = 0; f < a.length; f++)
        if ("object" != typeof a[f] || isArray(a[f]))
            "object" == typeof a[f] && isArray(a[f]) ? (b = d.insertCell(h),
            b.colSpan = 2,
            b.innerHTML = '<div class="td_head"></div><table style="width:100%">' + $(buildArray(a[f]), !1).html() + "</table>",
            c = !0) : p || (h += 1,
            p = !0,
            b = d.insertCell(h),
            m.empty = h,
            b.innerHTML = "<div class='td_head'>&nbsp;</div>");
        else
            for (var k in a[f])
                l = "-" + k,
                l in m || (c = !0,
                h += 1,
                b = d.insertCell(h),
                m[l] = h,
                b.innerHTML = "<div class='td_head'>" + encodeText(k) + "</div>");
    c || e.deleteRow(0);
    n = h + 1;
    for (f = 0; f < a.length; f++)
        if (d = e.insertRow(-1),
        td_class = isEven(f) ? "td_row_even" : "td_row_odd",
        "object" != typeof a[f] || isArray(a[f]))
            if ("object" == typeof a[f] && isArray(a[f]))
                for (h = m.empty,
                c = 0; c < n; c++)
                    b = d.insertCell(c),
                    b.className = td_class,
                    l = c == h ? '<table style="width:100%">' + $(buildArray(a[f]), !1).html() + "</table>" : " ",
                    b.innerHTML = "<div class='" + td_class + "'>" + encodeText(l) + "</div>";
            else
                for (h = m.empty,
                c = 0; c < n; c++)
                    b = d.insertCell(c),
                    l = c == h ? a[f] : " ",
                    b.className = td_class,
                    b.innerHTML = "<div class='" + td_class + "'>" + encodeText(l) + "</div>";
        else {
            for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
                b = d.insertCell(c),
                b.className = td_class,
                b.innerHTML = "<div class='" + td_class + "'>&nbsp;</div>";
            for (k in a[f])
                c = a[f],
                l = "-" + k,
                h = m[l],
                b = d.cells[h],
                b.className = td_class,
                "object" != typeof c[k] || isArray(c[k]) ? "object" == typeof c[k] && isArray(c[k]) ? b.innerHTML = '<table style="width:100%">' + $(buildArray(c[k]), !1).html() + "</table>" : b.innerHTML = "<div class='" + td_class + "'>" + encodeText(c[k]) + "</div>" : b.innerHTML = '<table style="width:100%">' + $(buildTable(c[k]), !1).html() + "</table>"
        }
    return e
}
function encodeText(a) {
    return $("<div />").text(a).html()
}
function isArray(a) {
    return "[object Array]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(a)
}
function isEven(a) {
    return 0 == a % 2
}

function log(a, e, d) {
    console.log(a)
}

;
```

Comment: Those are some ancient libraries (jQuery, Bootstrap) you have there. You can probably update to 3.x and 3.4.x, respectively, without issue.

Comment: Hi Yogi, Yes. Using node libraries to convert my json to Excel, I don't see the expected result. I get [object object] in case my json contains some arrays. Even if i customize this and stringify the object, I see conventional column headers and rows with specific columns containing huge data in the cells which is difficult to read. Hence converting to table would make json read easily. Details are mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009269/convert-complex-and-nested-json-to-table-in-excel-using-javascript